# Third level dropdown css won't show issue

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, submenu

I have a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/keltoid/BddYe/2/

I am trying to get a third level dropdown to work and I don't know why it isn't.

Under FABRIC 1 > FABRICS 2 > **I want Fabric Backings to drop another level when hovered over**.

I recently added everything from line 11 -21 (in jsfiddle) to try one more time to make it happen, and all I succeeded in doing was hiding the 3rd level, but can't get it to display when Fabric Backings is hovered over.

Any help anyone can give me is greatly appreciated.  I've saved this little dilemma for last and now my brain is fried and just can't seem to get the right ul li ul blah blah blah stuff's act together.

:)

Thank you in advance.

HTML:

```
   <ul id="menu">
     <li><a href="../../fabrics.aspx">FABRIC 1</a>
        <div class="menu-container-1">
          <ul class="column-1">
           <li><a href=""><span>Fabrics 2</span></a>
            <ul class="menu-container-5">
             <li><a href="~/products/U3/U13/U5.L24/Fabric-by-the-yard.htm">Fabric by Yard</a></li>                    
             <li><a href="~/backing.aspx"><span>Fabric Backings</span></a>
               <ul>
                 <li><a href="bss.com">BACKING ONE</a></li>
                 <li><a href="bss.com">BACKING TWO</a></li>
               </ul>                     
             </li>                     
             <li><a href="~/products/U3/U5/U5.L25/Minkee.htm">Minkee</a></li>
            </ul>
           </li> 
            <li><a href="~/products/U3/U6/U6.L2/ALL%20Fabric%20Collections.htm"><span>Fabric Collections</span></a>
             <ul>
              <li><a href="~/products/U3/U6/U6.L2/ALL%20Fabric%20Collections.htm">All Fabric Collections</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Color Collections</a></li>
             </ul>
              <li><a href=""><span>Soft Fabrics</span></a>
               <ul>
                <li><a href="">All Exclusives</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Cotton</a></li>
               </ul>
              </li>
             </ul>
            </div>      
           </li>
        </ul>
```

CSS:

```
 #top_base_nav {
    padding: 0;
    height: 30px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 1040px;  /* take this out for full width*/
    margin: -10px auto 20px auto;   /* also */
    background-color:#F9FCFE;

}

#menu li ul li ul li ul{
    border-top: 3px solid #FFFFFF;
    display: none;
    padding: 3px 10px;

}

#menu li ul li ul li: hover {
    display: block;

}

#menu {
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    width:1050px;
    margin:auto;
    height:30px;
    padding:0px 30px 0 0px;
    background:#ffffff;
    border:none;
    /* border around entire menu - v v all of these */
    /*box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 1px #e8edf0;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 1px #e8edf0;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 1px #e8edf0; */
}
#menu ul, #menu li {
    line-height:22px;
    text-align:left;
}

/* tab starts here */
#menu li {
    float:left;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
    padding:4px 30px;   /* good, leave  DON'T TOUCH! was 4px 8px  */
    margin:0;
    border:none; 
    /*border-right: 1px solid #E8F3FE;  */

    /* gradient */
    background:#F1F8FE;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #ffffff, #E2F2F7) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ffffff), to(#E2F2F7));
    box-shadow:inset .4px -2px 3px 2px #E0F1F7;
}

#menu li:hover {
    border-width:0;    /* borders between top nav links */
    padding:4px 30px;   /* good, leave  DON'T TOUCH!  PERFECT 7/9   was 4px 8px*/
    display:block;
    border-right-color:#B9C3CC;  /*not working but prob don't need */
}

/*   added 7/9 leave in, gives dropdowns the gradient..  */
 #menu li li {
    background:#ffffff;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #ffffff, #FAFCFE) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ffffff), to(#FAFCFE));
    box-shadow:inset .4px -2px 3px 2px #EFFFFF;
}

#menu li a {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:16px/1.8em;
    color: #000;
    display:block;
    outline:0;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:500;
}
#menu li:hover a {color:#161616;}

/* menu containers here  */
 #menu .menu-container-1, #menu .menu-container-2, #menu .menu-container-3, #menu .menu-container-4, #menu .menu-container-5{
    margin:4px auto;
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
    left:-999em;
    text-align:left;
    padding:5px 5px 3px 5px;
    border:1px solid #D8E9F8;    /* border around dropdown */
    z-index:1;  /*keep */
    /* rounded corners */
    border-radius:0 5px 5px 5px;
    -moz-border-radius:0 5px 5px 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:0 5px 5px 5px;
    /* gradient */
    background:#ffffff;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #ffffff, #FAFCFE) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ffffff), to(#FAFCFE));
    box-shadow:inset .4px -2px 3px 2px #EFFFFF;
}
#menu .menu-container-1 {
    width:175px;
}
#menu .menu-container-2 {
    width:346px;
}
#menu .menu-container-3 {
    width:330px;
}
/* for medley drops  */
#menu .menu-container-4 {
    width:350px;
}
#menu .menu-container-5 {
    width:175px;
}
#menu .menu-container-2 li .column-1, .menu-container-2 li .column-2 {width:175px}

/* need - hover over main item and  1st sub drops down  */
 #menu li:hover .menu-container-1, #menu li:hover .menu-container-2, #menu li:hover .menu-container-3{
    top:auto;
    left:0px;  /* moves container to left */
}
#menu li:hover .menu-container-4, #menu li:hover .menu-container-5 {top:0px; left:80% }

/*added 7/9 for span arrow sub menu */
 #menu span {
    display:block;
    overflow:visible;
    background-position:right center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    padding-right:0px;
}
#menu ul span {
    background-image:url("https://www.kqimageserver.com/other/arrowsub.png");
   /* padding-right:19px;   */
}
/*is sub menu */
 #menu ul ul {
    position:absolute;
    left:82%;
    top:4px;
}
#menu .column-1 {
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    margin:0;
}
#menu .column-2 {
    position:ABSOLUTe;
    margin:0;
    left:177px;
    top:0px;
     line-height: 24px;
     padding-top:5px;
    /*float:right;  */
}
#menu li:hover div a {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #eeeeee, 0 2px 0 #eeeeee;    /*lines between list items */
    color: #000;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding-left: 2px;
    font-weight:500;
    width: 175px;   
}

/*leave - sub sub background   */
 #menu li:hover, #menu li a:hover {    /* menu li a: WAS div a: hover but made all link hovers blue bg */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#04ACEC, #0186BA) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#04ACEC), to(#0186BA));
    color: #000;
    background:#deeff7; 
}
#menu li ul {
    /*box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #111111, 0 2px 0 #777777;  */
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin-bottom:7px;
}
#menu li ul li {
    float: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 24px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    width: 175px;
}
#menu li ul li:hover {
    background: none;
    border: medium none; /*changed to a color 10-17 didn't do anything */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
/* THIS IS WORKING!     *//*      third-and-above-level lists   */
 #menu li ul ul {    
    margin: 0 0 0 25px;
    z-index:1;  /*keep! */
}
#menu li:hover ul, #menu li li:hover ul, #menu li li li:hover ul, {
    /* lists nested under hovered list items */
    left: auto;
}

ul.column-1 li ul, ul.column-1 li li, ul.column-2 li ul, ul.column-2 li li {
    display:none;
}
ul.column-1 li:hover ul, ul.column-2 li:hover, ul.column-2 li li hover {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Rather than using all deep selectors like `#menu li ul li ul li:hover ul` you might try giving classes (either manually or with JQ) to the sub-menus like "level-1, level-2 etc) and using those...it makes things much easier.

Comment: Thank you Paulie - I would like to do exactly that - do you know where I can find a tutorial or something that will hit exactly how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
#menu li ul li ul li :hover  { 
    display: block;
}
```

with

```
#menu li ul li ul li:hover ul { 
    display: block;  
}
```

i.e:

a. remove space between `li` and `:hover`.

b. add `ul` to the end of the expression, as this is the element that should be effected

As @Paulie_D commented, you should consider using a sub-menu class to avoid all this muddy nesting.
If you choose to do so, be sure to use the direct child selector (`>`) to target only the immediate sub menu in the chain.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try your substitution and thank you for giving it to me.  I know the css is overwrought but don't have time right now to rewrite it all and I'm not all that sure what to do without considerable thought -- but I will let you know if this works -- thank you.

Comment: Got it! Thanks Matanya.

 Do you know of any quick resources that will help me reduce the css the way you suggest?

Comment: One more issue...  in IE the dropdowns are going behind some other elements...  I've tried z-index in different classes but doesn't make a difference. (cursed IE) Any thoughts?